# Issue with Loadfile mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to load a CSV file using loadfile on mariadb

Here is my loadfile

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/usr/src/salary.TXT' INTO TABLE salary
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'    
    (`EmpID`,@CHK_DATE,`CATEGORY`,`BASE`,`AMOUNT`)
    SET CHK_DATE=IF (@CHK_DATE='',null,STR_TO_DATE(@CHK_DATE, '%m-%d-%Y'));
```

This is how my salary.TXT file looks

```
EMP99 ,02-20-2016,Direct Deposit           ,             ,    721.77
EMP99  ,02-20-2016,Union Dues               ,      1092.06,     43.68
EMP99  ,02-20-2016,Labor Mgmt Coop Comm Fund,        39.50,      1.98
EMP99  ,02-27-2016,Direct Deposit           ,             ,    568.91
```

It is loading but all `CHK_DATE` is coming as `0000-00-00`

Not sure where I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when i tried running it within mysql it loads fine, When i try running it through shell script everything comes 0000-00-00

Comment: should't you then show us how exactly you are running it through a shell script?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid date as far as MySQL is concerned, generally you need to use the ISO `YYYY-MM-DD` format to avoid ambiguity. You may need to load this into a temporary table, then convert it over to your final schema using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) on the affected column:

```
INSERT INTO salary
  SELECT ..., STR_TO_DATE(source_date, '%m-%d-%Y'), ...
    FROM salary_import
```

Comment: Using an @variable is a perfectly valid way to avoid the need for a tmp table.  Since I don't see what is wrong with meso's attempt; tadman's suggestion is an alternative.